# How to rewrite this as a nested query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I was told to rewrite thie following query with a nested query without joins for better performance.  Is it true?  If so, how to rewrite it?

```
SELECT distinct A.Company_Name,C.Outlet_Name,
       C.Outlet_FCE_ID,D.Usergroup_Name
FROM   company A, PURCHASE_INVOICE B, 
       Outlet C, User_Group D,CT_USER E
WHERE A.Company_ID = B.Company_ID AND B.Outlet_ID  = C.Outlet_ID 
  AND B.Company_ID = C.Company_ID AND B.Username   = E.Username 
  AND E.Usergroup_ID=D.Usergroup_ID
```

Here is the table structure.

[image]

Comment: Why would nested queries generally perform better/worse than joins? That really depends on a lot of things. The actual problem might be related to the fact that you're selecting too much data and then removing duplicates using `distinct`. Why do you need the `distinct`? Can you show all relevant indexes on foreign keys, etc?

Comment: I'm curious as to this as well.  In my experience, assuming indexes are set up correctly, the optimizer is going to make the best use of joins than anything else.

Comment: If it runs slowly, check out the execution plan and/or run the SQL Profiler (don't use that against the production box though :) to see where the scans happen. Once you figure it out, suggest to add the indexes on the columns to your DBA. But I agree with other comments on joins against nested queries performance.

Comment: That is what I would like to know.  I was always under the assumption that joins are better.  If DISTINCT is a problem, I can add more creteria to eliminate the duplicates, but my question is, are nested queries perform better than joins?

Comment: Hey, maybe this could be a story for http://thedailywtf.com/ :)

Comment: Nested vs Joins, I think what we are saying is that "it depends".  Certainly, adding more criteria to remove the dupes is going to be better than a distinct.
You will find that 'it depends' is a very common answer in generic questions.  "Will an index improve performance?" "It depends"

Comment: it may need DISTINCT as it's getting to Outlet through Purchase_Invoice, which obviously could be multiples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question.  I don't like it this way, but here we go....

```
    SELECT  distinct
        ( SELECT    Company_Name
          FROM      dbo.COMPANY
          WHERE     Company_ID = p.Company_ID
        ) AS 'CompanyName' ,
        ( SELECT    Outlet_Name
          FROM      dbo.OUTLET
          WHERE     Company_ID = p.Company_ID
                    AND Outlet_ID = p.Outlet_ID
        ) AS 'OutletName' ,
        ( SELECT    Outlet_FCE_ID
          FROM      dbo.OUTLET
          WHERE     Company_ID = p.Company_ID
                    AND Outlet_ID = p.Outlet_ID
        ) 'OutletFCEID' ,
        ( SELECT    Usergroup_Name
          FROM      dbo.USER_GROUP
          WHERE     Usergroup_ID IN ( SELECT    Usergroup_ID
                                      FROM      CT_USER
                                      WHERE     Username = p.UserName )
        ) 'UsergroupName'
FROM    dbo.PURCHASE_INVOICE p
```

Answer (score 1):

The optimizer should get this right, but you may want to compare the the performance of the original query against this one:

```
select distinct 
    c.company_name, 
    o.outlet_name, 
    o.outlet_fce_id, 
    ug.usergroup_name
from company c 
    inner join (select distinct company_id, outlet_id, username from purchase_invoice) i on c.company_id=i.company_id
    inner join outlet o 
        on  i.outlet_id  = o.outlet_id
        and i.company_id = o.company_id
    inner join ot_user u     on b.username     = e.username
    inner join user_group ug on u.usergroup_id = d.usergroup_id
```

The distinct on the purschases table could eliminate some work, but I doublt if there will be that many dupes.

What would help more is an index on `purchase_invoice (username, outlet_id, company_id)`. This could speed it up because it would be a [covering index](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/covering-indexes/) on the table. The join would only have to look at the index and could skip reading the actual table. That helps if the table is wide.

Also note the order of columns in the index.I'm guessing that `ct_user` also has a lot of rows, and that it has a clustered index on `Username`. This way both the index and `ct_user` will be sorted on username, allowing a [merge join](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/28/sql-server-explanation-sql-server-merge-join/) for joining the two big tables.

Also please use join syntax and meaningful aliases for your tables like c fr company and ug for user_group. It shouldn't matter to the database but it defenitely helps humans trying to read your code. 
Also, allcaps LOOKS LIKE YOUR SCREAMING ALL THE TIME, but maybe that's just me :-)

GJ